# Disabling product carousel previews or annotations in Gmail (Promotions)

Tags: annotations, carousel, gmail-api, google-workspace, gmail-promo-tab

I am looking to NOT display product annotations or the product image/link carousel that pops up in promotions in the gmail app. We do not have this coded in, but seems to pull automatically.

This feature seems to automatically pull in images and links of products within the email HTML we use in a marketing emails and can look a bit spammy. It also decreases the visibility of the subject line and email details overall in the inbox on mobile.

Is there a way to override the feature within the schema so Gmail will not produce these in the promotions listings?